# How to receive a cookie on reactjs from nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm attempting to create a login where login data is sent to the nodejs server and if that login data is correct the server will send a JWT token through "res.cookie", what I would like to know is how will the reactjs client receive this cookie and also clear this cookie.

```
  app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
        const userData = {
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password
        }
        if(userData.email === email && userData.password === password){
          const payload = { email };
              const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {
                expiresIn: '1h'
              });
              console.log(token)
              res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true })
                .sendStatus(200);
        }else{
          res.send('incorrect params')
        }
        console.log(userData) 
  })
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt or a similar premade, well tested express-middleware authenticator, so you don't have to write any of this yourself?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm fairly new to react and node, ill have to look into express-jwt

Comment: You're setting the cookie with `httpOnly` flag. The cookie would not be available to read in JS land, but it will be send by the browser with subsequent requests.

Answer (score -2):

Here are the steps that need to happen.

1. User types their username and password and clicks sign in
2. Server receives credentials and validates them.
3. Server then creates a JWT for the users session and the server creates a cookie that contains the value of the jwt
4. the server simply returns and the cookie will be delivered as long as it is part of the response object.
5. hit control/command + i and view the cookie in chrome under your applications tab on the dev tools.

Also you probably want to use the nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser package to make your life easier.